# What kind of html ID's are these?

Tags: html, css

I was looking through gmail's source code in chrome and noticed that some elements have:

```
<div class="TO" id=":6e">stuff</div>

<div class="TO" id=":6f">other stuff</div>
```

I've never seen the use of ":" inside the ID. What's that for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does a colon mean within an HTML id attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544898/what-does-a-colon-mean-within-an-html-id-attribute)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can an ID attribute start with colon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713121/can-an-id-attribute-start-with-colon)

Answer (score 4):

They're just (valid) id's.

> There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; in particular, IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit, start with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc.

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan for some reason I thought ID's had to be alphanumerical

Comment: In **HTML4** an `ID` had to start with a-z/A-Z (though did allow certain special characters after it)

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess - but aside from the benefits of heavy minimizing and obfuscating that Google does, it also just happens to be a good anti-adblock tactic. If you're an avid fan of AdBlock, it's very hard to uniquely isolate an html element if the ids and classes are effectively random.